# preg_match $matches does not return special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, placeholder

I have a placeholder in my content which has the following format

`{{label1#label2_label3}}}`

And I'm correctly matching it with this regex

`preg_match('/\{\{(\w+|d+|_+|#+)*\}\}/i', $content, $matches);`

The problem is that the $matches array which PHP returns has the following data ([preg_match docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match))

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '{{label1#label2_label3}}' (length=44)
  1 => string 'label2_label3' (length=16)
```

While my expected output is the following

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '{{label1#label2_label3}}' (length=44)
  1 => string 'label1#label2_label3' (length=16)
```

My solution was to use a replace to simply get rid of the parenthesis like so:

```
$matches[1] = str_replace("}", "", (str_replace("{","",$matches[0])));
```

which works but I'm concerned about the performance while rendering a page with many placeholders.

Is there any flag or function I'm missing to just tell PHP to return the entire string inside {{ }} in $matches[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match)?

Answer (score 1):

Using `\w` also matches `\d` and `_` so that will leave `\w` and `#`

You get that result where `label1#` is missing as you repeat a capture group which will capture the value of the last iteration.

As you want a match for `label1#label2_label3` you can use a single character class to match word characters and the # char and use a non repeating capture group.

```
{{([\w#]+)}}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBcMv2/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/JRfik)

```
$content = "{{label1#label2_label3}}";
preg_match('/{{([\w#]+)}}/i', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{label1#label2_label3}}
    [1] => label1#label2_label3
)
```

---

If the `#` and `_` can not be at the start or at the end:

```
{{([^\W_]+(?:[_#][^\W_]+)*)}}
```

The pattern in parts:

- `{{` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ word characters without `_`
  - `(?:[_#][^\W_]+)*` Optionally repeat matching either `_` or `#` and 1+ word characters without `_`
- `)` Close group 1
- `}}` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TkEqQ7/1)